# Metasploit на Termux

Tags: termux

Пытаюсь установить Metasploit на Termux, выходит ошибка Could not find nokogori-1.8.0 ..., что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Всё, нашла решение: gem install nokogiri -v 1.8.0 — —used systems librariesbundle install -j5
Спасибо вот этому [форуму](https://codeby.net/threads/ustanovka-metasploit-na-termux.68433/), там на многие ошибки можно найти решения